# Is there a better pattern to match those words with regex?

Tags: strings, regex

Hello StackExchange community, I am curious if there is a better solution than mine for this exercise below:

*Enter a regex that matches all the items in the first column (positive examples) but none of those in the second (negative examples).*

**Positive Examples:**

```
pit
spot
spate
slap two
respite
```

**Negative Examples:**

```
pt
Pot
peat
part
```

**My solution:**
`^[a-z](?!ar|ea)[a-z]+\s?[a-z]+`

You can find the exercise here:

https://regex.sketchengine.co.uk/cgi/ex1.cgi

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `.*?p.t.*` keep it simple :)

Comment: @hjpotter92 That's what I was looking for! It felt like I was missing something or I could achieve this by a simpler solution than mine. Well I guess now it's time to learn more about lazy matches. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SpirosGkogkas `^[^pP].*$|^pit$` works too